# JQuery with DateTime Picker textbox align

Tags: jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

I have a form with a [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which calls an ajax that will print it's response in a textbox (which is a datetimepicker field as well), but when the JQuery function prints the response inside the input the align is sending the string to the right instead of it's normal properties.

[This is how it looks when the response is sent as a .val() to my input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpq2l.png)

But if I click the datetime picker item and insert it manually, it comes back to it's [normal style properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXwiJ.png)

The response will receive a datetime result converted to string

**HTML**

```
<label class="col-msg-4 control-label form-label">RETURN TIME:</label>
<br />
<div id="data_mov_Out" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="" readonly id="modalMoveRetorno" type="text"></input>
    <span style="height: 15px;"> </span>
    <div id="modalSaidaIcon" style="display:none;">
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="fa fa-clock-o" data-date-icon="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#data_mov_Out').datetimepicker(

            {
                language: 'pt-BR',
                maxDate: moment()
            }

        );
    });
</script>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/pro/lastReturn.php",
    data: {
        code: itemCode,
        place: itemPlace
    },

    success: function(response) {
        $('#modalMoveRetorno').val(response);
        $('#modalRetiradaIcon').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to use `$('#modalMoveRetorno').data("DateTimePicker").date(response)` instead of `$('#modalMoveRetorno').val(response)`

Comment: @Titus it gives me a "Cannot read property 'date' of undefined"

Comment: Have you initialised the `'#modalMoveRetorno` element as a DateTimePicker by calling `$('#modalMoveRetorno').datetimepicker();` ?

Comment: what about `$('#modalMoveRetorno').datetimepicker().date(response);`

Comment: @Titus edited my question. As you can see, my script is initialized right after the html

Comment: you have initialized $('#data_mov_Out') but you are missing $('#modalMoveRetorno') because you want to show a date when the ajax returns so try that line of code `$('#modalMoveRetorno').datetimepicker().date(response);`

Comment: You can change `$('#data_mov_Out').datetimepicker(.....)` to `$('#data_mov_Out, #modalMoveRetorno').datetimepicker(...)` and it should work.

Comment: @Titus still gives  "$(...).datetimepicker(...).date is not a function"

Comment: Try to use the suggestion in my first commend. If the element is initialised as a DateTimePicker, that should work.

Comment: just changing the $('#modalMoveRetorno').val(response) to $('#modalMoveRetorno').data("DateTimePicker").date(response), right? 

When I do this it gives me that  "Cannot read property 'date' of undefined"

Comment: @Titus I've changed to $('#data_mov_Out').datetimepicker({language: 'pt-BR',}).data("DateTimePicker").date(response); but the error now is Cannot read property 'date' of undefined